# Ruby, better way to implement conditional iteration than this?

Tags: ruby

I have an array `@cities = ["Vienna", "Barcelona", "Paris"];`

and I am trying to display the individual items with a spacer in between. However it is possible that there is only 1 element in the array, in which case I do not want to display the spacer. And also the array could be empty, in which case I want to display nothing.

For the above array I want the following output:

```
Vienna
-----
Barcelona
-----
Paris
```

I use an erb template `cityview` to apply formatting, css, etc before actually printing the city names. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
<p><%= @cities[@city_id] %></p>
```

I have implemented it as follows...

```
unless @array.empty?
    @city_id = 0;

    erb :cityview
end

unless @array[1..-1].nil? 
    @array[1..-1].each_index do |i|
        @city_id = i+1;

        puts "<p>-------</p>";

        erb :cityview
    end 
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Is this a Ruby or a Ruby on Rails question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer:

erb:

```
<p><%= @city %></p>
```

and loop

```
@array.each_with_index do |e, i|
    @city = e
    erb :cityview
    puts "<p>-------</p>" if i < @array.length - 1
end
```

I assume you have split the erb, bit because you want to customize it.

Answer (score 6):

```
@cities.join("<p>--------</p>")
```

*Edit to address the template*

Here I'm assuming that there's an `erbs` method that returns the rendered template without doing a puts. Returning the string allows easier manipulation and reuse.

```
@cities.map { |c| @city = c; erb :cityview }.join("<p>--------</p>")
```

Comment: I feel like I'm having a déjà-vu, since just two hours ago I wrote [this](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/7420214/comma-separation-in-a-ruby-loop/7420250#comment-8973446) on another similar question: "This is becoming kind of a general rule for Ruby and pretty much any other modern language: if you write a loop, chances are, you're doing it wrong and there is some higher-order method, higher-level iterator, combinator, helper or something like that you should use instead."

Comment: You'll have a problem if `@cities` contains something that isn't HTML-safe such as an ampersand.

Comment: It's not quite what I need because I want the erb template to render the object and it will also need the index (which I've called @city_id)

Comment: You could `render_to_string` and do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix HTML with your city names then you'll need to worry about HTML encoding things before you mix in your HTML. Using just the standard library:

```
require 'cgi'
html = @cities.map { |c| CGI.escapeHTML(c) }.join('<p>-----</p>')
```

If you're in Rails, then you can use [`html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) from `ERB::Util` and mark the result as safe-for-HTML with [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) to avoid having to worry about the encoding in your view:

```
include ERB::Util
html = @cities.map { |c| html_escape(c) }.join('<p>-----</p>').html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution would be to use a spacer template.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#spacer-templates